# Mocking controller actions in ASP.NET MVC2 with Rhino Mocks

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2, rhino-mocks

I am having trouble understanding how I can effectively and efficiently building a mocking unit test for a simple controller action that creates an instance of a viewmodel and passes it to a view.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IndexViewModel viewModel = new IndexViewModel();

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Can someone please give me an idea how I would write a unit test for a controller action that would ensure that the action generates an instance of a viewmodel class, and assigns it as the model for the view.

I understand, of course, that TDD says I should write the test first, and then build the above, but I having trouble grasping the fundamentals. An explanation of any code you pass on would be great, too. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a brief example of what you could do to test this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void IndexGetMethodReturnsIndexViewModel()
    {
        // Arrange
        HomeController controller = new HomeController();

        // Act
        ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;
        var viewModel = result.ViewData.Model as IndexViewModel;

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(viewModel);
    }
```

So you are calling the Index method on the controller, accessing the viewModel and making sure it is of type IndexViewModel and then you assert that it is not null.

Hope this helps.